# Multiple Interfaces declared in header

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone explain to me why Apple has various interfaces declared in NSArray.h?

And they declare

```
@interface NSArray: something something
```

and then they have this

```
@interface NSArray (NSExtendedArray)
```

Why do they use the NSExtendedArray in parenthesis? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The category—which is named by the thing inside the parenthesis—defines a logical grouping of methods to extend the class.  Using categories those methods can be in other header files as well.  For example, the `NSString` path extensions.